# Xdebug 3.0 in docker conteiner on Ubuntu not work - PhpStorm

Tags: docker, ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a problem. I set up listening debug in PhpStorm and is not working. I am convinced that I set up everything well. What might be the problem?

Docker compose:
[image]

Dockerfile:
[image]

Server setting:
[image]

Debug configuration:
[image]

PhpStorm debug listening:
[image]

Xdebug info:
[image]

Browser debugging:
[image]

Show my IP:
[image]

PhpStorm Xdebug settings:
[image]

Comment: Where is your PhpStorm Xdebug settings?

Comment: Side note: since you are using Docker on Linux ... consider adding `extra_hosts: - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"` to your docker-compose.yml file and use `xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal` instead of a hard coded IP (that changes on each build/run). From https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-763555307

Comment: @LazyOne https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRZEs.png

Comment: Thanks 1) I'm not sure if PhpStorm can listen on that many ports... Such option is per project ..so you can safely leave `9009` only for the moment. 2) Double check with `netstat` or alike that it is PhpStorm that listens on TCP 9009 (when "phone handle" icon is green/enabled in PhpStorm).

Comment: i run command in click phone handle: `netstat -an | grep 9009`
result: "tcp6       0      0 :::9009                 :::*                    LISTEN" 

and unclick phone handle:
i run command: `netstat -an | grep 9009`
result: "nothing", 

i check other port for example 9003. That is not working.

Comment: Based on that info it seems that PhpStorm is listening on IPv6 **ONLY** and not on IPv4. At the same time Xdebug tries to connect to IPv4 (172.17.xx.xx). Try forcing IPv4 for PhpStorm, e.g. add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to a file opened via `Help | Edit Custom VM Options` (this link shows other way around, but it should make it a bit more clear where and what to do: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#integrationWithProduct)

Comment: I haven't line with "Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" in vmoptions.

Comment: If you do not have such line then please do exactly what I have sad: add it there, save the file and restart the IDE.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I am check with line "Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" and with not this line.

blob:https://stackoverflow.com/601144ee-53f3-4d09-aba0-9e8eff9c5789
blob:https://stackoverflow.com/0157bcb3-5bba-4829-99b1-0c2c97ab241e

I don't have idea :(

Comment: Your last links are invalid. Please show a screenshot of  that file content with that suggested line present. Could be that you've entered it wrong... In either case: your Xdebug uses TCPv4 .. and your `netstat` shows that PhpStorm listens TCPv6 only (based on your info). So you need to make PhpStorm listening on TCPv4. If the suggested line does not work for some reason then look at your Ubuntu OS config -- disable IPv6 for the moment.